# How to insert all data from datagridview to access db

Tags: c#

I'm trying to insert all data from datagridview into access DB I tried a loop for to insert all rows it worked if I insert one cell but how to insert all cells

Can you help me with this?

```
      for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView2.Rows.Count; i++)
           {
               string str1 ="INSERT INTO tbl3(itemnamee,modelnumberr,pricese,countt,totalpricese) 
                          VALUES('" + dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[1-5].Value + "'); ";

               OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand(str1, con);
               cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();

           }
```

im getting error `Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.`

Answer (score 0):

I just figure out how

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView2.Rows.Count-1; i++)
           {
               string str1 ="INSERT INTO tbl3(itemnamee,modelnumberr,pricese,countt,totalpricese) VALUES('" + dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value + "','"+ dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value + "','"+ dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value + "','"+ dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value + "','"+ dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value + "'); ";
               OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand(str1, con);
               cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();

           }
```